# Android Action Hour after Screen Off

Tags: android

In my app, I want to perform an action one hour after the screen turns off.  If the screen wakes up before the hour passes, the timer should be reset.
I know how to set up the broadcast receiver to receive when the screen turns off, but what is the best way to start a timer after the screen turns off and perform an action when that timer runs out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alarm, set via AlarmManager.  Any other method won't wake up the phone to call the event.

```
    AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    registerReceiver( receiver, new IntentFilter("broadcast reciever class name here") );
    Intent i=new Intent("broadcast reciever class name here");
    PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);
    mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60*60*1000, pi);
```

Comment: I have no experience with AlarmManager.  You are saying that AlarmManager would be able to do what I need, though?  Thnaks, I'll look into it.

Comment: Any chance you have sample code or have a link to some? (I know that is asking a lot.)

Comment: Use the code in my edit.  Then just create a broadcast receiver that will respond to the alarm when it comes